# resolve 'called from wrong thread' exception

Tags: android, timer, onclick, textview

The purpose of my app is: User enters a number and clicks a button. The button uses the input to calculate the Fibonacci sequence with a timer - with each number in the sequence displaying each second to a textView. But when I try to run the timer I get the CalledFromWrongThreadException. I've posted my code below. As you can tell by my log statements I believe I know which line is causing the problem. I think it's because I'm calling a method which is outside my onclicklistener but when I move that other method around I just cause more problems.

I've read a couple other posts and I'm not really sure what the proper way is to print to a text area using my method. Does anyone know how I can make this work?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// primary widgets
private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;
private Button button1;

static int seconds = 0;
static Timer timer;

static ArrayList<Integer> fibList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final int delay = 1000;
    final int period = 1000;
    timer = new Timer();

    //Attempt to clear TextView
    textView.setText("");

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Clear Textview
            String array = " "; 
            fibList.clear();
            textView.setText(array);
            //Log.i("ARRAY", "ATTEMPT to CLEAR"+fibList);

            String input = editText.getText().toString();
            int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            int tmp = 0;

            // confirm input
            if (number < 20) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You entered: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
                    fibList.add(fib(i));

                    // sum even numbers
                    if (fib(i) % 2 == 0) {
                        tmp += fib(i);

                    }

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Number is too Large: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }


            //I believe error occurs in this method

             Log.i("TEST", "START TIMER");
             timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                    public void run() {      
                             Log.i("TEST", "RUN TIMER");
                        int nextIndex = setInterval();
                        Log.i("TEST", "SET INTERVAL");
                          if (nextIndex < fibList.size()) {
                              Log.i("TEST", "TRY TO PRINT");

                              //It looks like error occurs here when I try to print to textView
                              textView.setText(fibList.get(nextIndex)+ " ");
                              Log.i("TEST", "NEXT INDEX"+fibList.get(nextIndex));
                              Log.i("TEST", "DID PRINT");
                          }
                    }
                }, delay, period);
             Log.i("TEST", "END TIMER");

        }

    });

}

// run fibonacci sequence
public static int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}

//counts up for every element through the array
    public static final int setInterval() {

        if (seconds >= fibList.size())
            timer.cancel();
        return seconds++;

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: any time you have an Exception error, you should post the logcat

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
     textView.setText("aaa"); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your timer post a message to a Handler.  The handler will, by default, run on the main thread.  IT can then change the UI as needed, so just put the body of your timer into that handler.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Handlers. Are there any good tutorials out there?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and came on to StackOverflow to check out a solution. Didn't find anything proper but a little more *experimenting* with lot many Logs and debugging got me my solution.

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              textView.setText("Your String");                                     
    }                    
});
```

In my code, the problem was due to me accessing Two TextViews in seperate threads one after another using `TextView.post(new Runnable...)`. I guess this was due to it not being able to access UI Thread (as it was busy with previous thread changes). Setting both TextViews together in UI Thread solved the problem. So posting here for anyone else who might be perplexed by similar problem. Hope it helps.